# SED unterminated `s' command fails only on few servers

Tags: linux, sed

Getting following error:

```
Command:

binary_setup()
{
CRS_VERSION=`${GRID_HOME}/OPatch/opatch lsinventory | ${GREPCMD} "Oracle Database" | tail -1 | ${AWKCMD} '{print $(NF-0)}'`;
}


Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)

Command:
AWKCMD=`which awk`;
GREPCMD=`which egrep`;
SEDCMD=`which sed`;
CATCMD=`which cat`;
WCCMD=`which wc`;
TRCMD=`which tr`;
SORTCMD=`which sort`;
ECHOCMD=`which echo`;
PRINTFCMD=`which printf`;
COLUMNCMD=`which column`;

${CATCMD} $0 | ${GREPCMD} "HELP:" | ${GREPCMD} -v "GREPCMD" | ${SEDCMD} 's/^.*\crsstat\/\crsstat\/g';


Error:
/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 255: unterminated `s' command
/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

Comment: What is the `\c` escape sequence supposed to do in the regexp?

Comment: Looks like you escaped the second and third sed delimiters. `sed s/^.*\crsstat\/\crsstat\/g'` --> `sed s/^.*\crsstat/\crsstat/g'`

Comment: Since the command looks faulty, the more interesting question is: which servers does it work on and what is different about the sed version on those servers?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry, i mentioned the wrong one.

here is the original one which is still failing 

Original:
#${CATCMD} $0 | ${GREPCMD} "HELP:" | ${GREPCMD} -v "GREPCMD" | ${SEDCMD} 's/^.*crsstat/crsstat/g';

I tried your option, but it still fails :(
${CATCMD} $0 | ${GREPCMD} "HELP:" | ${GREPCMD} -v "GREPCMD" | ${SEDCMD} 's/^.*\crsstat/\crsstat/g';

Comment: Sed Version looks same on both working and problem server


sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1

Answer (score 2):

You're doing an `s/foo/bar` search/replace regex, but have no replacement term:

```
's/^.*\crsstat\/\crsstat\/g';
  ^--start search pattern
     + no unescaped /, so the pattern never ends
```

Perhaps

```
's/^.*\crsstat/\crsstat/g';
              ^--no \--^
```

instead?

Comment: or use another delimiter `s###` to avoid the need of escaping

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry, i mentioned the wrong one.

here is the original one which is still failing 

<<Original>>:
#${CATCMD} $0 | ${GREPCMD} "HELP:" | ${GREPCMD} -v "GREPCMD" | ${SEDCMD} 's/^.*crsstat/crsstat/g';

I tried your option, but it still fails :( --> 
${CATCMD} $0 | ${GREPCMD} "HELP:" | ${GREPCMD} -v "GREPCMD" | ${SEDCMD} 's/^.*\crsstat/\crsstat/g';